# Groovy dependency conflict when running JMeter with a custom jar in lib directory

Tags: jmeter

I have a Java project that includes dependencies on other maven projects including rest-assured (4.1.2).  This has a dependency on groovy (2.5.8).  I need to use functionality from this project in JMeter, so I dropped the jar for that project into the lib directory for JMeter.  When I run JMeter, however, it's unable to load the JSR223 Sampler.  In the log, there's an error due to a dependency conflict.  JMeter is expecting groovy 3.0.11 but instead is finding groovy 2.5.8 due to my custom jar.  If I upgrade rest-assured to the latest, then my custom jar is including groovy  4.0.6.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the conflict?  Can I tell JMeter to use a newer version of groovy?

```
2023-02-24 13:21:21,009 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:206) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineFactory.getLanguageVersion(GroovyScriptEngineFactory.java:95) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223BeanInfoSupport.<clinit>(JSR223BeanInfoSupport.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:2338) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(InstanceFinder.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(InstanceFinder.java:66) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.beans.finder.BeanInfoFinder.find(BeanInfoFinder.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Introspector.java:467) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:417) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI.<init>(TestBeanGUI.java:162) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGuiFromCache(GuiPackage.java:417) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:266) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:237) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:554) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:199) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.doActionAfterCheck(LoadRecentProject.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:717) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) ~[?:?]
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 4.0.6 and you are trying to load version 3.0.11
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:534) ~[custom-framework-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve it through my java project by excluding groovy from the rest-assured dependency and adding the groovy dependency with same version as JMeter. That works.

For example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic Jar Hell, you need to ensure to have the same .jar versions of a library in your project classpath.

You can try using i.e. [RestAssured 4.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.5.0) which depends on [Groovy 3.0.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/3.0.9), my expectation is that you shouldn't have any problems with this.

If you cannot amend your project dependencies you can remove Groovy from JMeter completely by deleting `groovy*` jars from the "lib" directory of your JMeter installation and use [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) samplers or [create your custom JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) invoking your project code in JMeter script.